# scraping nested webpage for specific text

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<tr id="inmate_201700220865">
    <td class="row ">3</td>
    <td class="row "><a href="javascript:" onclick="getInmatePreview(201700220865)">View</a>
    <input type="hidden" id="bookingPhoto_201700220865" value="http://bookings.example.org/201708/20170826.AA8">
    <input type="hidden" id="bookingPhotoFile_201700220865" value="20170826.AA8">
    <input type="hidden" id="bookingPhotoFolder_201700220865" value="201708">
    <input type="hidden" id="bookingPhotoName_201700220865" value="LAST, FIRST LAST">
    <input type="hidden" id="inmateID_201700220865" value="277497">
    <input type="hidden" id="index_2" value="201700220865">
    <input type="hidden" id="curIndex_201700220865" value="2"></td>
    <td class="row ">LAST<input type="hidden" id="bookingLastName_201700220865" value="LAST"></td>
    <td class="row ">FIRST<input type="hidden" id="bookingFirstName_201700220865" value="FIRST"></td>
    <td class="row ">LAST<input type="hidden" id="bookingLastName_201700220865" value="LAST"></td>
    <td class="row ">08/26/2017</td>
    <td class="row ">41</td>
    <td class="row ">M</td>
</tr>
```

I am attempting to scrape the last 6 lines of text from this table. I am having difficulty without performing nested loops through Beautiful Soup. I'm sure there is an easier way, but for the record I just need the Last  name, First name, Last name, and the last three lines which are DOB, Age and Gender. Below is my code which returns the entire `tr`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

#beautiful soup scrape
scraped = urlopen('http://www.example.org/inmates/').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(scraped, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all('tr',{'id' : re.compile('^inmate') }):
    for name in item ('td',{'class'  : "row alt"}):
        print (item)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all the `tr` tags and get the texts using [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method. Then [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the text by `\n` and remove the empty strings using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). Here you get all the data you need in one line.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

#beautiful soup scrape
scraped = urlopen('http://www.example.org/inmates/').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(scraped, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all('tr', {'id' : re.compile('^inmate')}):
    data = list(filter(None, item.get_text().split('\n')))
    print(data)
```

**Output**

```
['3', 'View', 'LAST Name', 'FIRST Name', 'LAST Name', '08/26/2017', '41', 'M']
```

If you want to remove the first 2 elements then just `slice` the list

```
data = list(filter(None, item.get_text().split('\n')))[2:]
```

**Output**

```
['LAST', 'FIRST', 'LAST', '08/26/2017', '41', 'M']
```

Comment: I haven't checked thus but I'm certain it will work. Thank you.